# Как преобразовать один формат телефонного номера в другой?

Tags: javascript, php, html

В админке wp вводится номер в формате +7 (812) 324-99-73, нужно вывести его в атрибут href="tel:..." в другом - +78123249973. Я искал похожие решения, но нашел только преобразователи в обратную сторону.

Comment: `'+7 (812) 324-99-73'.replace(/[^\d\+]/g, '')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если не заморачиваться с маской, и просто в лоб решить, то так:

```php
$phone  = '+7 (812) 324-99-73';

// всё что не число, заменяем на пустую строку
$newPhone = preg_replace('/\D/','',$phone);
$newPhone = '+'.$newPhone;

var_dump($newPhone);
```